# Big Sur - Detecting when the screen has turned off

Tags: screen, power-management

Is there a way under MacOS Big Sur (11.7.3) to detect when power-saver mode has kicked in and the screen has turned off?

I want to have a special utility run every time the screen turns off.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **NSWorkspace** notification [`NSWorkspaceScreensDidSleepNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacescreensdidsleepnotification) is issued when the display sleeps.

For a CoreFoundation approach see the Stack Overflow question [Check if display is at sleep or receive sleep notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929731).

Comment: Thank you! That discussion refers to a "sleepwatcher" command, and it's exactly what I need.  I'll test it when I can return to my Mac later this week.

Comment: And I've now been able to test "sleepwatcher", and it works perfectly on my Mac. Thank you again!